# How to draw a curve according to a control points list that has more than 3 points

Tags: android

I want to draw a curve according to a control points list. 
This is what I expected:
[image]

Here are the control points:
(0,90)
(1,100)
(-3,145)
(10,150)
(23,155)
(73,108)
(80,120)
(86,131)
(40,210)
(50,220)
(60,230)
(148,185)
(140,180)
(131,175)
(23,188)
(0,190)

Here is my code:

```
public List<PointType> controlPoints;
public void render(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        int size = controlPoints.size();
        if (size < 2) {
            return;
        }

        paint.setColor(this.color);
        paint.setStyle(this.style);

        Path curvePath = new Path();
        PointType firstPoint = null;
        PointType beginPoint = null;

        for (PointType point : controlPoints) {
            if (firstPoint == null) {
                firstPoint = point;
            } else if (beginPoint == null) {
                beginPoint = point;
            } else {
                curvePath.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
                curvePath.quadTo(beginPoint.x, beginPoint.y, point.x, point.y);
                firstPoint = beginPoint;
                beginPoint = point;
            }
        }

        canvas.drawPath(curvePath, paint);
    }
```

But the result is this:

[image]

What's wrong and How can I draw the correct curve?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3813349/794088

Comment: You need to smooth the curve out, approximating it with lines will always look something like that.  Look into Bezier splines as a first attempt

Comment: https://github.com/autotrace maybe you can take something from this link.. it seems you need more points as it draw straight lines ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by below code:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        int size = controlPoints.size();
        if (size < 2) {
            return;
        }

        paint.setColor(this.color);
        paint.setStyle(this.style);

        Path curvePath = new Path();
        curvePath.moveTo(controlPoints.get(0).x, controlPoints.get(0).y);
        for (int idx = 1; idx < controlPoints.size(); idx += 3) {
            curvePath.cubicTo(controlPoints.get(idx).x,
                    controlPoints.get(idx).y, controlPoints.get(idx+1).x,
                    controlPoints.get(idx+1).y, controlPoints.get(idx+2).x,
                    controlPoints.get(idx+2).y);
        }

        canvas.drawPath(curvePath, paint);
    }
```