# How to draw custom shape in android using canvas in viewgroup

Tags: android, canvas, draw, shapes, viewgroup

I want to create a shape like this image.

[image]

I searched a lot for drawing on canvas with different shapes.

I didn't got anything on StackOverflow or Google.

[Here](http://%20https://varun.ca/polar-coords/) is the link I referred

In [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142-android-custom-view-tutorial) tutorial I got to know how to use the curves with canvas.quadTo();

[Android How to draw a smooth line following your finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287949/android-how-to-draw-a-smooth-line-following-your-finger/8289516#8289516)

[How to draw a curve according to a control points list that has more than 3 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915250/how-to-draw-a-curve-according-to-a-control-points-list-that-has-more-than-3-poin)
//here i got to know about canvas.cubicTo() method which will give curves from start point to end point with middle point.

I don't have any code to show, so, I need to start from scratch.

I need this to be created as `ViewGroup`, so that I can add 1 `View` to this `ViewGroup`. If I add another `View` into this `ViewGroup` then the background should look like this.

[image]

Comment: that is what i am not able to understand, where to start. can u plz help me

Comment: Hi @pskink I read about canvas, and i am not able to draw the shape which i want. The only thing i am getting is drawing line, rectangle, oval, and using canvas curves.

Comment: canvas.drawPath is giving me the line to draw, but how make rounded curves.

Comment: Path.cubicTo and quadTo is to draw lines. If i am not mis understood. cubicTo requires a middle point where we can have curves b/w two points. right??